# Registering separate clicks for every Spanned string

Tags: android

My app need such scenario like in a textView I stored "@dev will goto home and @Roy will go to Station. I want to open a dialer activity to call the clicked person.

But using this code if I click on any @words it shows whole string. 
am toasted string.

User can enter his own string and may be he/she enter or not the @contact and there is not defined index of the same.

```
multiAutoCompleteTextView.setText(addClickablePart(desc), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
private SpannableString addClickablePart(String str) {
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(str);
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[@]\\w*");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        ClickableSpan clickableSpan = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View textView) {
                // do toasting

                TextView b = (TextView)textView;
                String buttonText = b.getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(ViewNote.this,buttonText,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        };
        ss.setSpan(clickableSpan, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    }
    return ss;
}
```

Comment: So where is the clicked person's contact information stored?

Comment: and what do you want to show?

Comment: i have a separate query for that. from this i just want send the name to next activity.

Comment: so you want `dev` or `Roy` for instance?

Comment: user can click on any words like "@roy" or "@dev". i just need to send the clicked name further.

Comment: `matcher.toString()` should do it then

Comment: where i have to right matcher.tostring?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android ClickableSpan get text onClick()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19750458/android-clickablespan-get-text-onclick)

Comment: would you relate my case? @JarettMillard. please. because "@person_name can be anywhere in the string. i don't know the index. and i am poor in this case.

Comment: @DevendraSingh Read the accepted answer on that question. It matches your use exactly.

Comment: @JarettMillard i really don't know how and where i can make changes. in both codes. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the text which is associated with each `ClickableSpan`. Try something like this:

```
public static class ClickableSegmentSpan extends ClickableSpan {

        private String segment;

        public ClickableSegmentSpan(String segment) {
            this.segment = segment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            Toast.makeText(widget.getContext(), segment, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The `addClickablePart` method would change to this:

```
private SpannableString addClickablePart(String str) {
        SpannableString ss = new SpannableString(str);
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[@]\\w*");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            int start = matcher.start();
            int end = matcher.end();
            ss.setSpan(new ClickableSegmentSpan(str.substring(start, end)), start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        }
        return ss;
    }
```